# CSS + jQuery: scale, center and rotate images inside container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transforms

If you take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/0spv56uk/1/

I am creating something on a website that has a container.
This container cannot get any wider (it may be able to get lightly taller - to fir the size of the screen)

Inside this container I will be setting images. They all vary in size.

These Images/SVGs have ability to rotate on click of a button (As shown in code).
I'm using 90 degrees at the moment but may need it at 45 degrees later.

The issue I have is that the image overflows the container when rotated.
I need it to scale inside the container when rotated. (The bottom of the container should be expandable but not the top).
I've looked over other threads here, and they either hard-code the scale(which only works if you have single image) or the code does not really apply to me so well.

Thank you all in advance.

This has been giving me nightmares for some time.

Here is my code

```js
var myArray = ['0deg', '90deg', '45deg','180deg','270deg']; var myIndex = 1; 
function nextRotation() { return 'rotate('+myArray[myIndex++%myArray.length];+')' };

$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#testImg').css('transform', nextRotation() );
    $('#testImg').css('-webkit-transform', nextRotation() );
    $('#testImg').css('-moz-transform', nextRotation() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick=document.getElementById('testImg').src='https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/smile.svg'>Img1</button>
<button onclick=document.getElementById('testImg').src='https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/juanmontoya_lingerie.svg'>Img2</button>
<button onclick=document.getElementById('testImg').src='https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/php.svg'>Img3</button>
<button type="button" id="btn1" >Rotate Div</button>

<DIV id="container" style=" wid th:60%;border-style:dotted;">

  <DIV id="outer" width="100%">
    <img id ="testImg" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/smile.svg"   style="width:100%;height:100%;">
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get it working by matching the height of the image to the width of the container. I also made container's position relative.

Note that you're also working with transparency in the image, so that is making it look like it's leaving a bunch of empty space.

I just added :

```
$('#testImg').css('height', $('#container').width() );
```

[This looks to be working, but may stretch the image](https://jsfiddle.net/fdc432p6/2/#&togetherjs=B9wLjIbRU2)

Comment: I thought about something like this but. It appears to be too stretchy, and doesn't work at 45 degree angles. I'm assuming there's got to be some kind of math computing where the edges are and scaling it down.

Comment: I've been playing with something like this, but cannot get it to scale once i remove rotate https://jsfiddle.net/jhcn4f2w/

Comment: So what are you looking for when rotating, for example, 45degrees? Should the image corners just get cutoff/hidden by the border if needed, or does the image need to shrink so that ALL corners are still contained and visible?

Comment: they should be like in this fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/jhcn4f2w/   The only issue i have is that the container bottom does not expand. I want to give the bottom a max size and min size